# Is there a way to scan a txt file for a word or name in c++?

Tags: c++, text-files

So I am attempting to make a log in for the beginning of a game and I have programmed the registering of the names and passwords. But is there a way to scan the file for one of those user names?

:)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is..

Comment: You should read a good book on C++ before beginning to make a game.

Comment: The proper way to store this information is with a database. And also you should look into proper password encryption.

Comment: Moreover, you can easily google tis program source code.

Comment: This is one of the first things they teach when dealing with file I/O in C++.

Answer (score 4):

There is "find a word in a file" available in C++:

```
typedef std::istream_iterator<std::string> InIt;

if (std::find(InIt(std::ifstream("file.txt") >> std::skipws), InIt(), word) != InIt())
{
    std::cout << "the word '" << word << "' was found in 'file.txt'\n";
}
```

For this to work `word` needs to be delimited by whitespace: The `std::istream_iterator<std::string>` class reads object of type `std::string` from the stream it is constructed with and gives iterator access to the corresponding sequence. The default-constructed `std::istream_iterator<std::string>()` is used to indicate the end of the sequence. `std::find()` is just one of the standard algorithms looking for an object in a sequence matching its last argument, in the above case `word`.

What's a bit odd about the code is the use of the `std::ifstream` object: Since the result is just a Boolean expression, a temporary `std::ifstream` is used. Since constructor of `tsd::istream_iterator<std::string>` takes a `std::istream&` as constructor argument and a temporary cannot be bound to a non-`const` reference, a manipulator (`std::skipws`) is inserted: this operation has no effect other than returning a non-`const` reference to the temporary `std::ifstream`.

Comment: And it looks so easy to read. I wish I could have come up with that one... ;)

Comment: I apologize but how does one delimit of white space? And wow everyone else said there wasn't one of those functions.

Comment: @Caveman: Well, whitespaces are characters like space (` `), newline (`\n`), carriage return (`\r`), etc. (there are one or two more but I don't recall their escape sequences). To delimite a word by whitespace you would just have one or more of these characters on either side of the word. Why everyone else said that the functionality isn't there I don't really. It seems they are not used to combine avaiable functions and classes to obtain the desired functionality.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Maybe `typedef std::istream_iterator<std::string> InIt` would have helped. The key expression would become: `std::find(InIt(std::ifstream("file.txt).rdbuf()), InIt(), word) != InIt()`

Comment: I like it alot... But where is "word" gone?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I don't understand what you asked

Comment: @DietmarKühl: to my (lesser) knowledge, do you actually need the `.rdbuf()`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Good point: it went missing. I have added it back to the appropriate location.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think `std::istream_iterator<T>` takes a `std::istream&` as constructor argument but `std::ifstream("file.txt")` is a temporary which cannot be bound to a reference. Using `rdbuf()` gets me an object which I thought cant be used to construct an `std::istream_iterator<T>` (but I mixed that up with `std::istreambuf_iterator<cT>`). So, something else is actually needed, e.g., `>> std::skipws` (I'll update the answer with the findings from the comments...)

Comment: @MooingDuck: The perils of typing on a mobile device and testing the code (especially the latter). Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not a "find a word in file" function, no. You'll have to open, read the file and scan for the word in each section (e.g. line, block) of the file you have read, and then close the file.

Comment: Could i do that with for statements or while statements how would you recommend I do it?

Comment: @Caveman It's essentially irrelevant, the essential is grasping a little bit of algorithmic thought.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in text mode and read it line by line. For each line, scan it for the word you're looking for.

That's about it. I know of no single function you can call to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat names.txt 
user1
user2
user3



$ cat c.cc

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string STRING;
    const char *USERNAME = "user1";
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("names.txt");
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        getline(infile,STRING); 
        if (strcmp(USERNAME,  STRING.c_str()) == 0) 
                cout<<STRING;
    }
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}


$ ./c
user1
```

Use strncmp if you want to have the lines be

```
username1 password1
username2 password2
```